# How to get transaction cost in smart contract - Solidity, Ethereum

Tags: ethereum, solidity

How would I get the transaction cost inside of my contract? Would it just be: `tx.gasprice` ? And will this always be a value in gwei or will it be wei ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cost of a transaction isn't really known until execution completes. In an extreme example, perhaps your function which is computing this is being called by another function, and after you return, that function `throw`s, consuming all remaining gas. There's no way for you to know in advance that this will happen.

To calculate the cost of the transaction, you'd need two pieces of information:

1. The gas price.
2. How much gas will be consumed.

If you knew both, you could multiple them together and get the total cost. `tx.gasprice` tells you (1), but as explained above, you can't really know (2). The best you can do is probably to use `msg.gas` at the top and bottom of a function to tell you roughly how much gas *that function* consumes.