# How to reliably estimate the Chainlink VRF cost in LINK client side?

Tags: ethers.js, chainlink

I'm using Chainlink's VRF V2 direct funding method and I want to pass the cost of the random words callback to the account initiating the transaction. I have figured out what my callback gas limit should be and I have created a helper method in solidity to return the estimated cost at run time. It looks something like this:

```
function oracleFee(uint256 _gasPrice) external view returns (uin256) {
  return VRF_V2_WRAPPER.estimateRequestPrice(vrfCallbackGasLimit, _gasPrice); 
}
```

The function to request randomness looks something like this (note the code to ensure the sender has enough LINK and approved the spending):

```
// This method is called by another external function
function requestRandomness(uint32 _callbackGasLimit) internal returns(uint256 requestId) {
  console.log("Gas price === %s", tx.gasprice);

  uint256 cost = VRF_V2_WRAPPER.calculateRequestPrice(vrfCallbackGasLimit);
  uint256 balance = LINK.balanceOf(msg.sender);
  require(balance >= cost, "Insufficient LINK balance");

  uint256 allowance = LINK.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
  require(allowance >= cost, "Insufficient LINK allowance");

  LINK.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), cost);

  requestId = requestRandomness(
    vrfCallbackGasLimit,
    RANDOM_WORDS_REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
    RANDOM_WORDS_REQUEST_SIZE
  );
}
```

All I need is to get the proper gas price client side and call my `oracleFee()` method to figure out approximately how much LINK the wallet should have and how much it should approve for spending.

But the problem I'm running into is that I can't get even close to the value that `tx.gasprice` returns in the `requestRandomness()` method. I'm using ethers js and while there are two ways I found to read the gas price - `provider.getGasPrice()` and `provider.getFeedData()`, the value returned by these methods is way off. In the case of `getFeedData()` the returned value is almost 7 times lower than `tx.gasprice` and the `getGasPrice()` returns something even lower than that.

I can't use ethers' `myContract.estimateGas.requestRandomness()` because if the user doesn't have enough LINK it'll revert as you can tell by the code it's calling inside (chicken and egg situation sort of)

What causes this discrepancy in gas price readings? I'm using hardhat and ethers v 5.7.2 by the way.

Comment: I think this may be because gasprice is the price of gas, not the cost incurred in executing the transaction?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245051/how-to-get-transaction-cost-in-smart-contract-solidity-ethereum

Comment: @ZeusLawyer I understand that, but the gas price is what I need for my `oracleFee()` function, yet the values I read in three different places are not the same. I need to be able to read the same value as `tx.gasprice` but from ethers (at least a close enough value)